# Flutter button alignment

Tags: flutter, frontend

I am very new to Flutter development. I am trying to make a button that would be on the bottom right of the page, but it is not working.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class GoBack extends StatelessWidget {
  const GoBack({required this.onGoBack, super.key});

  final void Function() onGoBack;

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: onGoBack,
      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(208, 93, 0, 255),
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero),
        minimumSize: const Size(60, 60),
      ),
      child: const Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
        Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_left_rounded),
      ]),
      );
  }
}
```

I tried adding:

```
alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
```

I am probably using this wrong tho.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better for you to use `floatingActionButtonLocation` property of `Scaffold` widget. You can customize the button style with the `FloatingActionButton` widget.

```
return Scaffold(
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.small(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_left_rounded),
  ),
  body: ...
);
```

You can visit https://blog.logrocket.com/flutter-floatingactionbutton-a-complete-tutorial-with-examples/ or https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html to see more details.

Answer (score 0):

you might use FloatingActionButton within Scaffold.

```
Scaffold(
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(),)
```

It is located at right bottom by default.

Check documentation here :
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html

You can also use

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat
```

Therefore you can play with button location.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I believe this is what you want. It is the minimum viable code, under 30 lines. I hope it works. Feel free to provide acknowledgement in the comment below.

```
class GoBack extends StatelessWidget {
  const GoBack({required this.onGoBack, super.key});
  final void Function() onGoBack;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: onGoBack,
            style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(208, 93, 0, 255),
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(),
              minimumSize: const Size(60, 60),
            ),
            child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_left_rounded),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```